# Plugin Extended E-mail Notification does not see the groovy-template file in $ {JENKINS_HOME} / email-templates /

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-email-ext

Hello recently I started using jenkins Extended E-mail Notification plugin. Based on the example groovy template, I decided to create my own template for e-mail messages. First, I created the catalog $ {JENKINS_HOME} / email-templates / and gave it the owner jenkins and full read and write capabilities of chmod 775. I upload my file with the name knife-html.template and then send an e-mail:  `'''$ {SCRIPT, template = "knife-html.template"}'''...`

I receive an e-mail in my inbox with:

```
 Groovy Template file [knife-html.template] was not found in $ JENKINS_HOME / email-templates.
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help

Comment: We need to see the code to assist.

Comment: `$ {JENKINS_HOME}` exists only on the controller. Your job is probably running on a node/agent on a different server, hence the error. No idea on a solution as I don't use the function. Provide more details, incl. link to example. Also, why do you show spaces in the path?

Comment: The problem was solved. Unfortunately, I am using docker jenkins and I cannot create an email-templates folder there. I solved the problem using the Config File Provider add-on
(https://plugins.jenkins.io/config-file-provider/)
It allows you to add your own email-extension templates.